How can I make an Average per hour in R if my data is per minute?
I am new at using R.
I want to make an average per hour and then make graph plots.
My data is something like this:
ID                date.                    pm25
DQMJZ9801.    2024-09-01 06:01:31.         5.42
DQMJZ9801     2024-09-01 06:04:59          5.62
DQMJZ9801.    2024-09-01 06:07:48.         6.00
DQMJZ9801     2024-09-01 06:10:38.         5.42
DQMJZ9801.     2024-09-01 06:13:30.        6.83
etc...
I hope you can help me, thank you !
My data is per minute,

It looks like you have sporadically timed samples that in the example data are every 3 minutes or so. Do those represent samples in time where the value is presumably in the same neighborhood in between, or are they triggered by an event, such that the values in between are near zero? (I presume the former?)

The general approach I would take would be first to make sure "date" is a datetime type variable, then something like library(tidyverse); df |> mutate(hour = floor_date(date, "hour") |> summarize(avg = mean(pm25), .by = hour) |> ggplot(aes(hour, avg)) + geom_line()

This takes the average of all values in each hour for each id assuming that the input is as in the Note at the end.  With the data shown there is only one such group so we get one line out but if there were more we would get more.
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  group_by(id, hr = trunc(as.POSIXct(date), "hour")) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(pm25), .groups = "drop")
## # A tibble: 1 × 3
##   id        hr                    avg
##   <chr>     <dttm>              <dbl>
## 1 DQMJZ9801 2024-09-01 06:00:00  5.86

Note
DF <- data.frame(
  id = rep("DQMJZ9801", 5L),
  date = c("2024-09-01 06:01:31", "2024-09-01 06:04:59", "2024-09-01 06:07:48",
         "2024-09-01 06:10:38", "2024-09-01 06:13:30"),
  pm25 = c(5.42, 5.62, 6, 5.42, 6.83)
)


In base R (no external packages needed), we can do
transform(df0, hour = trunc(as.POSIXct(date), "hour")) |>
  aggregate(pm25 ~ id + hour, mean)

#         id                hour  pm25
# 1 DQMJZ9801 2024-09-01 06:00:00 5.858
# 2 DQMJZ9801 2024-09-01 07:00:00 5.080
# 3 DQMJZ9802 2024-09-01 07:00:00 7.180


Note
Modified input data.
df0 = structure(list(id = c("DQMJZ9801", "DQMJZ9801", "DQMJZ9801", "DQMJZ9801", 
                            "DQMJZ9801", "DQMJZ9801", "DQMJZ9801", "DQMJZ9802"), 
                     date = c("2024-09-01 06:01:31", "2024-09-01 06:04:59", "2024-09-01 06:07:48", 
                              "2024-09-01 06:10:38", "2024-09-01 06:13:30", "2024-09-01 07:33:30", 
                              "2024-09-01 07:33:30", "2024-09-01 07:34:30"), 
                     pm25 = c(5.42, 5.62, 6, 5.42, 6.83, 4.83, 5.33, 7.18)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

